# How to get nearby POIs

Tags: gps, distance, coordinate-systems

I have a database with Points of Interest that all have an address.

I want to know what is the **method/name/call** to get all **nearby** POIs from a given position.

I understand that I need to convert all my addresses to LAT / LON coordinates at least, but my question is:

for a given LAT / LONG how do I get from the database/array what POIs are nearby by distance, for example:

You are here 0,0
 nearest POIs in a **2km radius** are:

- POI A (at 1.1 Km)
- POI C (at 1.3 Km)
- POI F (at 1.9 Km)

I have no idea what should I look into to get what I want :-(

Any help is greatly appreciated.
**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know what is the method/name/call to get all nearby POIs from a given position.

Calculating the [great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between two latitude/longitude coordinates is easy with the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). You may want to read further and check out the implementation at [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) by Chris Veness.

> For a given LAT / LONG how do I get from the database/array what POIs are nearby by distance?

If you will only have a handful of POIs, you can simply calculate the great-circle distance from your point to each POI. Then simply sort the result list by the distance.

However, if you will be having many POIs, you should consider using a database with [spatial indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index) capabilities. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html), [PostgreSQL](http://postgis.refractions.net/) and [SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/spatial-data.aspx) all have geo-spatial features (either natively or via extensions), which include spatial indexing and implementations of the haversine formula.